# How to solve. error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale

Tags: python, opencv, compiler-errors

**Hello** I have "error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale"

```
xml = './haarcascade_hand.xml'
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + xml)
```

This Code not working...

But another file is work

EX)

```
xml = './haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + xml)
```

Why do this?

I saw in another question that "error: (-215) !empty() in function detectMultiScale" can be solved by modifying the file path.

But i have the files all in the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there is no such file in cv2.data.haarcascades as it can be seen [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades).

You should download the "haarcascade_hand.xml" from [this project](https://github.com/avelino/python-opencv-detect/blob/master/haarcascade_hand.xml) or any other repo that you have in mind, then provide the full path for this to work.

it should look like this

```py
cascade_path = "fullpath_to_hand_cascade/haarcascade_hand.xml"
hand_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_path)
```